# Application Only Authentication with the LinkedIn API

Tags: c#, api, linkedin-api, hangfire

I fear that the answer to this is that this is no longer supported, but I'm trying to find a way to use Application Only authentication against the LinkedIn API.

The application is running as a Hangfire job (and therefore, without user interaction), with a view to querying the LinkedIn API and pulling in some basic post information from my own account.

I'm having trouble finding a library or even a method to authenticate with the API with just my Client ID and Secret (for example) without having to redirect a user in order to get an access token.

Does anyone know if this is still possible?

Comment: Hi Chris , what kind of  "basic post information from my own account." do you need ?.
i believe that the api is used to get some data about the user itself

Comment: Hi ilan, ideally I'd like to pull in the list of posts that the account has made

Comment: aren't you saving the token when the user first logged ?